# What's considered the most reliable deployment of OpenSSH?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, openssh, windows-server-2012-r2

I have to install OpenSSH on some Windows Server machines (2008 R2, 2012 R2, 2003).
I see there are some deployments ([this one](http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html) from Wikipedia and [another one](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) on GitHub and there might be more).

What's the best one in terms of reliability and stability?
I can't understand what are the differences of these deployments.

I prefer to install an EXE rather than compile it by myself.

Comment: to the one who downvote it... what's bad in this question??

Comment: Hello, the last one is linked to the Powershell Team according to the repo, so Microsoft official. I'd say it can't be better than this so far.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong? The question is [opinion based](https://superuser.com/tour) and is about [software recommendation](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Non of them is on-topic here.

Anyway, the difference between these two are:

- first one is working for a quite long time under cygwin, which means that it is proved by many users.
- the other one is official by Microsoft (since they, 20 years after all the other systems, realized it might be useful). It has a big pro that it is native win32 version running without any other middle-layer (cygwin).

I would go with the second one, since it is (finally) native. But it is opinion and I am aware that somebody can disagree. This is the reason for the first paragraph.